# DataSet Inserts take progressively longer

Tags: c#, sql, strongly-typed-dataset, sql-server-ce-4

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914143/data-inserts-take-longer-for-more-iterations-executed?noredirect=1#comment40563756_25914143) I am running through a datatable, using the data to fill a new dataset for the purposes of data migration.

The migration inserts into a data set then every 5000 records the added rows get saved to the database using EricEJ SqlCeBulkCopy method.

My problem is that for the first amount of records (5000 ish) the average milliseconds taken per record is around 150-200, but it gradually increases. at record 11000 this figure is now at around 475 milliseconds.

I have a typed data set with EnforceConstraints turned off.

The actual database write always takes less than a second so I am pretty sure it is not the database itself, so I am left with the code taken longer to run each iteration, which could be down to the code itself or something I am not realising about datasets.

Could the dataset be increasing the time because it is using indexes or some keys that are not turned off by using the EnforceConstraints = false property?

One other thought is that I am checking to see if a record exists before inserting it, so I have tried both the Linq methods .ANY() and FirstOrDefault() != null

I iterate through a datatable, for each record I read some values then pass them to this method.

```
 private int MigrateItems(string reference, string brand, string captureSite, string captureOperator, DateTime captureDate, DateTime addedDate, DateTime updatedDate, bool retain)
        {
            //prepare the inputs
            reference = reference.Trim();

            int brandID = -1, databaseUpdateID = -1, captureID = -1, insertedRowID = -1;

            //get the foreign keys
            brandID = MigrateBrands(brand);
            databaseUpdateID = MigrateDatabaseUpdates(reference);
            captureID = MigrateCaptures(captureSite, captureOperator, captureDate);

            //if the item doesn't exist then add it
            bool exists = dataSet.Item.FirstOrDefault(a => string.Equals(a.Reference, reference, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) == null ? false : true; ;
            if (exists == false)
            {
                var insertedRow = dataSet.Item.AddItemRow(brandID, databaseUpdateID, captureID, reference, retain, updatedDate, addedDate);
                insertedRowID = insertedRow.ID;
            }
            else insertedRowID = dataSet.Item.Single(a => string.Equals(a.Reference, reference, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ID;
            return insertedRowID;
        }
```

Once 5000 records have been iterated or all records have been done then I call this method:

```
private void BulkInsertData()
{
     using (var bulkCopier = new SqlCeBulkCopy(connectionString))
     {
        bulkCopier.DestinationTableName = dataSet.Brand.TableName;
        bulkCopier.WriteToServer(dataSet.Brand.Where(a => a.RowState == DataRowState.Added).AsEnumerable());


        //(same code for all the tables)

        //change all row states to unchanged
        dataSet.AcceptChanges();
     }
}
```

I'm using the following:

- C#
- Visual Studio 2012
- Sql Server Ce 4.0

Comment: Probably you should post the code that handles this work. Otherwise it will be a wild guess to find the problem.

Comment: There is a lot of it! I was mainly asking for peoples experiences of DataSets and whether or not This has happened to other people.

Comment: Without seeing the actual code, any responses that you get will just be opinion based and maybe be unrelated to your problem. Try and just show some relevant parts of your code.

Comment: DataSets have huge overhead, and do not scael. why not simply use a List<MyClass>. SqlCeBulkCopy does not require you to use DataSets

Comment: Because I need to keep track of the other tables so that I can set up foreign keys and stuff like that. I Have accepted that it will take me 8 hours or so to run now so its ok really.